# Configuring <service>endpoint address in WCF server web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I can't find what influence has configuration of `<service>` section `endpoint address` in `web.config` file. If I comment all available '' and start my WCF on ASP website project in Visual Studio, WCF Test Client utility starts and allows function call anyway like it did in uncommented case. And it is possible to go to standard page at `http://localhost:35168/kmNNN.svc` address in browser with information regarding WSDL and service usage samples like I did previously.

How to test service is available at address defined in `endpoint address`?

How I can test that MEX service is started? I was thinking I can go to address http://localhost:35168/kmNNN.svc/MEX and see something in browser, but this doesn't work.

web.config:

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="kmNNNwebSrv.WCFJSproxyBehavior">
      <!--<enableWebScript/>-->
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MEX">
      <serviceMetadata/>
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<services>

  <service name="kmNNNwebSrv.kmNNNDevice">
    <endpoint address="" 
              behaviorConfiguration="kmNNNwebSrv.WCFJSproxyBehavior"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="kmNNNwebSrv.IkmNNNDevice">
    </endpoint>
  </service>

  <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MEX">
    <endpoint
        address="MEX"
        binding="mexHttpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>


</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config file not explicit. I think your service is kmNNNDevice declarec in kmNNNwebSrv namespace. hoep it helps
 take this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section  ...-Your Conf-...></section>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
     <add ....-Your connection string-.></add> 
  </connectionStrings>

  <applicationSettings>
  </applicationSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior" name="NamespaceOfYourService.YourService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding.NamespaceOfYourService" contract="NamespaceOfYourInterface.YourInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:port/YourService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBinding.NamespaceOfYourService" transferMode="Streamed"
                 closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

        </binding>

      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```